# Can you be petrified while in gaseous form?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic, conditions

A high level Wizard cast a spell on an Efreet I had summoned from an Efreet Bottle.  This spell restrained him and forced him to make CON saves at the end of each of his turns. I cast the spell [Gaseous Form](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/gaseous-form) with the Efreet. He didn’t save quick enough and was turned to stone. In the end everything turned out great. But I’d like to know if turning into a gas would prevent petrification. I am playing D&D 5e. I don’t know what spell was cast by the way, I thought it was all awesome and flavorful. Just trying to learn more about 5e and it’s many nuances.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could update your post with a better description of the events from 3 years ago :).

Answer (score 21):

### No

If the spell used was *[flesh to stone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/flesh-to-stone)*, the spell says:

> If the target's body is made of flesh, the creature must make a Constitution saving throw.

Gas cannot be counted as "flesh".

Comment: Not only are you right, but that is the only spell option that can deliver a petrified condition. You may want to add that tidbit :) You can also cite the spell language that matches OP's events of restrained, saves, and then petrification.

Comment: @NautArch Technically, *prismatic spray* and *prismatic wall* could do it too, but... yeah those hardly count

Comment: @Medix2 Darn you, Dndbeyond! Searched for petrified condition on spells and those didn't come up. You are right in that they do qualify, but both likely would have had a slightly different description by OP :)

Comment: Couldn't it be argued that the target's body is still made of flesh, it is just in a gaseous state?

Comment: @MichaelRichardson Sure it could be argued, the adjudication of which would be up to the DM.  The gaseous form spell says you transform a creature "into a misty cloud". It does not explicitly say "the target is no longer made of flesh", but I would certainly rule that a misty cloud is not flesh.

Comment: It might not be quite as simple as this. From the question, it sounds like *Gaseous Form* was cast **after** *Flesh to Stone*, in an attempt to "counter" the petrification. Which means that when *Flesh to Stone* was cast, the target probably *was* flesh and blood.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson You are right in that it's unclear - but I'm not sure we're going to get an update.

Comment: @NautArch Still, it might help if the answer indicated whether the order of casting matters.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson there's definitely room for improvement here. Hope they do!

Comment: @Jack And that is the perverse beauty of 'spells only do what they say they do'.  It _says_ you are a misty cloud - but _doesn't say_ you are no longer made of flesh.

Comment: In the question, *Gaseous Form* is cast only after the "flesh" saving throw. There is no flesh requirement after that, the following saving throws just talk about "a creature".

Comment: Also *Gaseous Form* does not seem to end the "Restrained" condition, so that's no help either.

Comment: And to clean things up: Being petrified doesn't end the status of being a creature, so a petrified creature is still a eligible target for spells that target creatures. [J. Crawford tweet](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/966507846664781824)

Answer (score 11):

### Yes, a gaseous creature can be petrified.

The Petrified condition states:

> A petrified creature is transformed, along with any nonmagical object it is wearing or carrying, into a solid inanimate substance (usually stone). *(PHB, 291)*

Petrification specifically turns the creature *into a solid*. If they are gaseous due to the effect of some spell, petrification makes them solid, so they are still affected.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the reply! That’s what I assumed just getting a second opinion!

Comment: A gas turning into a solid without becoming a liquid first? WITCHCRAFT!

Comment: Liquified efreet?  ew.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym add two dashes of bitters, half a lime, a jigger of rum and two ounces of club soda.  Pour over ice, stir, and serve.

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli  Witchcraft...or [deposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deposition_(phase_transition)#:~:text=Deposition%20is%20the%20phase%20transition,sometimes%20deposition%20is%20called%20desublimation.)

Comment: @kirt - You seem to know an awful lot about witchcraft. *narrows eyes suspiciously and starts stacking wood*

Answer (score 2):

I am going to make an assumption, that the enemy(?) Wizard used *Flesh to Stone* spell or equivalent effect on the Efreeti, because the description matches that:

> You attempt to turn one creature that you can see within range into stone. If the target's body is made of flesh, the creature must make a Constitution saving throw. On a failed save, it is restrained as its flesh begins to harden.

So, the Efreeti failed the save and became restrained (the somewhat relevant part: *"A restrained creature's speed becomes 0, and it can't benefit from any bonus to its speed."*).

Then you (the OP's character) cast *Gaseous Form* on the Efreeti. The relevant parts of that spell's description:

> You transform a willing creature you touch, along with everything it's wearing and carrying, into a misty cloud for the duration.
>
> The target [...] has advantage on [...] Constitution saving throws. [...] The target can't fall and remains hovering in the air even when
> stunned or otherwise incapacitated.

There's nothing which indicates the *Restrained* condition would end, so you have a misty cloud with speed 0, unable to do anything much. The petrification proceeds:

> A creature restrained by this spell must make another Constitution saving throw at the end of each of its turns. If it successfully saves against this spell three times, the spell ends. If it fails its saves three times, it is turned to stone and subjected to the petrified condition for the duration. The successes and failures don't need to be consecutive; keep track of both until the target collects three of a kind.

So these saving throws proceeded to their unfortunate (for the Efreeti) conclusion, despite the CON save advantage, really unlucky (I'd verify that the DM remembered to use the advantage). Finally, after 3-5 turns, petrification completes, and this part of it is relevant here:

> A petrified creature is transformed, along with any nonmagical object it is wearing or carrying, into a solid inanimate substance (usually stone).

So, yep, **the Efreeti would be subject to petrification**, while still also being subject to *Gaseous Form* for a few more rounds.

---

Now things get a bit more unclear. Let's see [combining magical effects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CombiningMagicalEffects):

> The effects of different spells add together while the durations of those spells overlap. The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don't combine, however. Instead, the most potent effect--such as the highest bonus--from those castings applies while their durations overlap, or the most recent effect applies if the castings are equally potent and their durations overlap.

So, we have two different spells, and their effects should add together. But being both inanimate solid substance and a misty cloud seem mutually exclusive. Or maybe they aren't. DM has two options:

- A simple solution is to adapt above rule for different spells with contradictory effects, by taking the most potent (*Flesh to Stone* is level 6 spell, vs level 3 for *Gaseous Form* without upcast) or the most recent (while *Flesh to Stone* was cast first, the petrified condition is more recent). So usually the *Gaseous Form* would be suppressed until it ends (assuming petrification became permanent).

  If the *Gaseous Form* would instead suppress the petrification (maybe because of upcasting), then the Efreeti would stay in the misty cloud form for the duration, with no effects from petrification, and then immediately become petrified when it ended (assuming petrification became permanent).

  So, nice and simple, either you're a misty cloud, or you're a statue, but not both, no nasty corner cases or intermediate states.
- A DM might also decide, that sure, these effects can overlap. So, the misty cloud form of the Efreeti is suddenly inanimate, solid and quite heavy. Being petrified does not suddenly make the Efreeti an invalid target for *Gaseous Form*, either, since it is very much not incorporeal. At this point, the DM probably needs to decide what the misty cloud actually looks like - does it look like the original creature, just made of mist, or does it look like a small roundish cloud, or something else? In any case the petrified cloud will still hover, because being *"otherwise incapacitated"* does not end hovering, and this covers being petrified.

  Once the *Gaseous Form* ends, the statue falls down. It is an inanimate solid statue, but still, this is *magic*, and there doesn't seem to be anything which could prevent this, so it becomes statue of the original non-cloud Efreeti.

  Still, DM might also quite reasonably decide that being petrified exactly preserves the form at the moment of petrification, because it is specified to be solid and non-aging. In that case, if petrified condition is removed (eg. by *Greater Restoration* spell), the original form should be restored, as this is what normally happens when a magical transformation suddenly loses its magic, like in anti-magic field. If there was a risk of death or damage, it should be in the rules (save, DC, damage dice).

**In any case, in the end the Efreeti will be petrified until restored.**

Comment: Given it is not clear, can your answer cover both scenarios? That bounty could be yours!

Comment: @NautArch You mean, petrified misty cloud and petrified Efreeti scenarios? Sure, I can expand on that... tomorrow.

Comment: Basically I think if you can cover each interpretation, that'd be great!

Comment: @NautArch Made an edit... Except I'm still not 100% happy with my logic. Hmm...